# Freertos Cortex M3 - Port Yield jumps back to main()

Tags: freertos

im currently implementing freertos on a efm32gg mcu.
i use a startup thread to initialize the project.
this thread disables context switch (TaskSuspendAll) during the project initialization where other modules create their threads, so the initialization is only interrupted by interrupts, not by other threads.
at the end of the project initialization, the startup thread enabled context switch (ResumeAll).

the current demo project adds 1 thread which would blink a led.
as soon as the startup thread enables critical sections, which leads to the portYield call at some point, the application jumps back to the main() (I dont know if through a reset or through a call to main).

but when i just use the startup thread and keep the project initialization function empty, then as desired, freertos keeps running the idle task..

does someone have an idea what the reason for such a behavior could be?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to creating threads while the scheduler is suspended, see number list item 9 on the following page of the FAQ, which basically says not to do that.  The reason being that creating a thread may result in a context switch being needed (if the thread has a priority above the thread that created it), but if the scheduler is suspended that can't happen:  https://www.freertos.org/FAQHelp.html

If you want to have an initialisation thread that creates other threads, but you don't want the other threads to run yet, then I would recommend having the priority of the initialisation thread above that of any threads it creates - then the scheduler won't choose any other threads.  At the end of initialisation you can lower the priority of the initialisation thread, or just delete it, whichever is most appropriate.

I suspect in your case the board is being reset somehow, so you need to find the source of that.